# How did they solve the compressor stall issue of the F-14A in the B?

Tags: f-14

I know that the F-14A was notorious for having compressor stalls during high AOA or with quick thrust changes, and most of the issues were solved in the B. Externally there doesn't seem to be much difference in the intake, so how did they solve it?

Comment: The F-14A and B have different engines.

Comment: @efe Thanks, I know but specifically what made them not suffer from the same issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grumman changed the F-14 powerplant from the Pratt and Whitney TF-30 engine to the General Electric F-110 engine when the F-14B was developed.  This not only provided the airframe with an extra 16,000 lbs of thrust compared with the old TF-30 engines but also a much more stable, reliable gas core as compared with the P&W design.  I don’t know if they have managed to wring out the issues in the F119 and F135 engines, but Pratt and Whitney engines have been notoriously finicky and prone to compressor stalls if not petted nicely.  GE engines, particularly military aircraft engines, are some of the most robust and reliable jet engines out there.